# Prove that the sum of Cauchy distribution random variables divide by a infinite sequence convergence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent identical random variables of standard Cauchy distribution (i.e. the density is $\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$). Let $n \to \infty$ and consider the random variable $S_n=X_1+,...,+X_n$.

1. Prove:  $\frac{S_n}{a_n}\rightarrow0$ a.e. iff $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}<\infty$.
2. Try to give the necessary and sufficient conditions for which  $$
   \frac{\max(X_1,...,X_n)}{a_n}\to 0 \quad\text{a.e.}
   $$

**My ideas so far**:

1. For problem 1, given  $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}<\infty$, I would like to prove that $\frac{S_n}{a_n}\rightarrow0$: by Kroencker lemma, I just need to prove that $\sum\frac{X_n}{a_n}<\infty.$ Then I do it by applying Kolmogorov three series theorem: thus I can easily prove the convergence of $\sum\frac{X_n}{a_n}$. But how to prove the converse? What can I deduce from $\frac{S_n}{a_n}\rightarrow0$? Maybe I should try to use characteristic function?
2. For problem 2, I think maybe there is some way to convert $\frac{\max(X_1,...,X_n)}{a_n}$ to a similar form as in problem 1: am I right?

Thanks in advance for any tips or help in general.

Comment: You sure about the first problem? In my opinion $\frac{S_n}{a_n} \to 0$ a.e if and only if $\sum_n \frac{n}{a_n} < \infty$. This (and similarly problem (2)) can be easily established with the help of Borel Cantelli lemma.

Comment: @Dominik Kutek
 I think it is not a necessary and sufficient condition, please see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma). And, can you give a specific proof of how to use Borel Cantelli lemma to answer problem (1) and (2)? Many thanks!

Comment: It's not what I'm asking. Kronecker Lemma isn't an iff statement, whereas Borel Cantelli in the case of independent variables is (in some sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for (1) and (2) is the same, summability of $1/a_n$.

First the easy case: If $\sum 1/a_n$ **diverges**, then $X_n>a_n$ infinitely often.
Therefore  $R_n:=S_n/a_n$ cannot tends to zero because
$$\frac{X_n}{a_n}= R_n- \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}R_{n-1} \, $$
as noted by @p4sch.

Also, under the assumption of divergence of $\sum 1/a_n$, the ratio
$$\frac{\max(X_1,...,X_n)}{a_n} \ge \frac{ X_n}{a_n} $$
does not tend to 0.

Conversely, if $\sum 1/a_n$ **converges**, then instead of Kronecker's lemma, one can  use a dyadic argument.

Since $Q_\ell:=S_\ell/\ell$ is a standard Cauchy variable for any $\ell \ge 1$,
we have
$$  P\left[\frac{|S_{2^{k+1}}|}{a_{2^k}}>\epsilon\right] = 
P\left[ |Q_{2^{k+1}}| > \epsilon \frac{a_{2^k}}{2^{k+1}} \right]\le C\frac{2^k}{\epsilon a_{2^k}} \quad (*)\,,
$$
where $C$ is a constant.
Now the RHS of (*) is summable in $k$, because for each $k$,
$$ \frac{2^k}{a_{2^k}} \le 2\sum_{j=2^{k-1}+1}^{2^{k}} \frac{1}{a_j} \,.
$$
Thus,
$$\limsup_k \frac{|S_{2^{k+1}}|}{a_{2^k}} \le \epsilon \,, $$
almost surely, so (intersecting these events over $\epsilon=1/m$ for all $m$) we obtain that
$$\limsup_k \frac{|S_{2^{k+1}}|}{a_{2^k}}=0\, $$
almost surely.

To interpolate, use the first Ottaviani-Levy inequality, see the first inequality in A.1.2 (page 431) in [1]. (or see [2], [3]). We obtain
$$   P\left[\max_{n\in (2^k, 2^{k+1}]} \frac{|S_n|}{a_n} \ge \epsilon\right] \le P\left[\max_{n\in (2^k, 2^{k+1}]} |S_n| \ge \epsilon a_{2^k}\right] \le    2 P[  |S_{2^{k+1}}| \ge \epsilon a_{2^k}] 
\le 2C\frac{2^k}{\epsilon a_{2^k}} \,.$$

This is just twice $(*)$, so almost surely,
$$\limsup_n \frac{S_{n}}{a_n}=0\,. $$
Also, in this case,
$$\frac{\max(|X_1|,...,|X_n|)}{a_n}  \to 0
$$
almost surely using the same logic and the second Ottaviani-Levy inequality in the same reference.

[1] https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4757-2545-2%2F1.pdf
[2] Billingsley, P. (1995) Probability and Measure, 3rd ed., Theorem 22.5, p. 288.
[3] Kai Lai Chung, A course in probability theory, 3rd ed., P. 126

Comment: Cauchy r.v.'s are not non-negative. $\lim \sup a_n \leq 0$ does not imply that $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Why $\frac{max(X_1,...,X_n)}{a_n}\leq \frac{S_n}{a_n}$ when $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges?@Yuval Peres

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy and  
Knotnet- I corrected my answer following your comments- Is it OK now?

Comment: It seems OK to me!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a remark, that something cannot be true in the Problem, as already pointed out in the comments.

It's an easy exercise to calculate the characteristic function of $\frac{S_n}{a_n}$, denote it by $\varphi_n(t)=e^{-\frac{n|t|}{a_n}}$. Now for instance take the sequence $a_n=n\log n$ (with $a_1=1)$, then we see that $\varphi_n(t)\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, hence the random variables $\frac{S_n}{a_n}$ must converge to $0$, but the series $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ is not convergent.

Comment: Your conclusion seems to be not complete: The random variable converges in measure and, since the limit is a constant, we have P-stochastic convergence as well. But you cannot conclude that $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$ a.e. Or I am missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the comment from @p4sch. This also makes me confused.

Comment: With  $a_n=n\log(n)$, the variable $D_k=(S_{2^{k+1}}-S_{2^k})/2^k$, is standard Cauchy, so we have $P(D_k>a_{2^k})>c/k$, and the second Borel Cantelli Lemma yields that $D_k>a_{2^k}$ infinitely often. This implies that $R_n:=S_n/a_n$ cannot tend to 0 a.s. since $D_k/a_{2^k}=(a_{2^{k+1}}/a_{2^k}) R_{ 2^{k+1}}-R_{2^k}$

Answer (score 0):

First, we should note that the event
$$\{ S_n/a_n \rightarrow 0 \}$$
is an element of the terminal $\sigma$-algebra $\tau((X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})$, since $a_n \rightarrow \infty$. So the probability of this event is $0$ or $1$.

Moreover we can compute $$\mathbb{P}(|S_n|>\delta a_n )$$ explicitly by noting that the the sum of independent standard cauchy distribution has a cauchy distribution with scale parameter $n$. (This can be checked by determining the characteristic function of $S_n$ and Levy's theorem.)

So, using the symmetry of the density, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(|S_n|>\delta a_n ) =\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\delta a_n}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t \leq \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{n}{\delta a_n}.$$
Thus, if the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty n/a_n$ is convergent, we can conclude (by the simple part of the Borel-Cantelli lemma) that $\mathbb{P}\{ S_n/a_n \rightarrow 0 \} =1$ holds.

We see that the our simple argument, based on the Borel-Cantelli lemma, is not strong enough. In fact, we should procced by your argument: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/a_n$ converges a.e. if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X_n|> a_n) <\infty.$$
As we have already seen, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X_n|> a_n) \leq = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{a_n} \frac{1}{1+t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t \leq \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}.$$
So, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n} < \infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/a_n$ converges a.e. and now Kronecker's lemma implies that $\frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \rightarrow 0$ a.e., as claimed.

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/a_n$ is divergent, we note that
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > a_n) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{a_n}^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2} \,\mathrm{d} t = \frac{2}{\pi}(1- \arctan(a_n)).$$
Thus, we find that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > a_n)$ is divergent as well. By the second part of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we conclude that $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > a_n \text{ for infinty many } n \in \mathbb{N}) =1.$$
Thus, if $S_{n}/a_n \rightarrow 0$, then
$$ \frac{X_n}{a_n} = \frac{S_n}{a_n} - \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \frac{S_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}} \rightarrow 0,$$
since $a_{n-1}/a_n \leq 1$ by monotonicity of the sequence $(a_n)_n$. Therefore $\{S_n/a_n \rightarrow 0 \}$ is a nullset.